# Where to find good Dravidian language sources to translate words like இர்ரேண்டம்?

Tags: reference-request, vocabulary, language-comparison, hindi

I am interested in studying ancient trade between Egypt and India.

I found this word to describe the sea as "burn red"?

The word is இர்ரேண்டம்

Google translate will pronounce it but will suggest a very different word. Meaning Second.

How to find this word etymology?

Maybe Tamil or Hindi or one of dozens of other Indian languages.